# How to store value at array index using ARM?

Tags: arrays, arm

I am trying to write a while loop in ARM that checks if an array position contains a dash, if it does not, it will subtract the offset by 7 and check again. If it finds the dash, it will store an 'X' symbol there. When I run this, I get a segmentation fault. My prediction is that it is something wrong with the way I am storing it at the very last line of the program.
Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
 /*Store input into array*/
store:    
    ldrb    r4,[sp]          /*store the value at sp in r4*/
    add     r4, r4, #34      /*increase r4 by 34 to give the offset*/
    ldr     r5, =array       /*r5 points to the first index in array*/
    mov     r2, #0x2D        /*r2 contains the dash symbol '-'*/
storeWhile:     /*While loop for store*/
    ldrb    r6, [r5,r4]      /*r6 contains address of array + the offset*/
    cmp     r6, r2           
    beq     empty            /*if(array[offset] == '-') branch*/
    sub     r4, r4, #7       /*else, subtract offset by 7*/
    cmp     r4, #0           
    bge     storeWhile       /*if(offset >= 0) branch back to start of loop*/
empty:  
    mov     r2, #0x58
    str     r2, [r6]         /*Store r2 (Uppercase X) into posotion at array + offset (r6)*/
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are getting "segmentation faults" then you are doing memory management, either in hardware or with an OS. You haven't told us what processor you are using or your run time environment. You need to provide a great deal more information before you can get useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mov     r2, #0x58
str     r2, [r6]
```

doesn't really make sense. Store instructions (`str Rd, [Rn]`) saves Rd in Rn. You probably want something like this

```
mov     r6, #0x58
str     r6, [r5,r4]
```

You should be also use `subs` instead of `sub` then `cmp`.